# Check login not work in Symfony2

Tags: php, authentication, symfony, doctrine-orm, roles

i am try configure the firewall to autenticate users. This step work fine, because when i put a wrong user in the login form, the application return the message "Bad credentials.", but when the user and password are correct, the application fails trying get the user roles.

My entity user is called "Usuario" and my entity Rol is called "Perfil". In my user entity have this code:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppsManantiales\CommonBundle\Entity\Perfil")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="usuarios_perfiles",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="idUsuario", referencedColumnName="idusuario")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="idPerfil", referencedColumnName="idperfil")}
 * )
 */
 protected $perfiles;

/**
 * Get perfiles (getter auto generated)
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
 public function getPerfiles()
 {
     return $this->perfiles;
 }

/**
 * Hook method
 */
 public function getRoles() {
     return $this->getPerfiles()->toArray();
 }
```

The process of login was failing with this message:

> Error: Call to a member function getRole() on a non-object

In this file:

> /vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/DataCollector/SecurityDataCollector.php
>   line 60

So, check the cited line:

> array_map(function ($role){ return $role->getRole();},
>   $token->getRoles()),

And, debug with var_dump:

```
var_dump($token->isAuthenticated());
var_dump($token->getUsername());
```

Last lines, returns correct data, but when try this:

```
var_dump($token->getRoles());
```

var_dump show an array with wrong data:

> array (size=2)   0 => string 'ccraig' (length=6)   1 => int 3

'ccraig' string is a value, of the actual user entity instance, but the other value no idea.
Obviouslly, this values not understand the "getRole" method of my Perfil (Rol) entity.

So, why not get the true array of roles ?.
I test the getRoles method in other controller (with the same user) an works fine:

```
$doctrine = $this->getDoctrine();
$users = $doctrine->getRepository('CommonBundle:Usuario');
$user = $users->find(8);
$perfiles = $user->getPerfiles();
$out = $perfiles->getValues();
var_dump($out);
```

var_dump show:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(AppsManantiales\CommonBundle\Entity\Perfil)[405]
      protected 'idperfil' => int 3
      protected 'nombre' => string 'ROLE_DOCENTE' (length=12)
      protected 'administrador' => boolean true
      protected 'paginaDefault' => null
  1 => 
    object(AppsManantiales\CommonBundle\Entity\Perfil)[406]
      protected 'idperfil' => int 1
      protected 'nombre' => string 'ROLE_ADMIN' (length=10)
      protected 'administrador' => boolean true
      protected 'paginaDefault' => null
```

Any ideas ?. Im newest in Symfony.
Thanks!.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was easy. I should not return an array o Role Object. I should return an array of Role name (string).